# How to find char 0x1A (→) in DB2 database

Tags: sql, db2

Recently, DB2 team gone for database upgrade and 2 days later again degraded because of incompatible version with Application. Mean while in few DB tables 0x1A (→) chars got inserted. How to find that chars over all DB tables. Any idea please help.

Comment: Why is it tagged with Oracle? What version and platform of Db2? What is the column data type? Is the column value exactly that character value?

Comment: You have to generate a series of select statements on every table having string columns where you expect such values. How do you want to get the result exactly? Selecting all column values for such a record? Using some additional indicator column with particular column name having such a character?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
CREATE TABLE FIND_VALUE (
    TABSCHEMA  VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
,   TABNAME    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
,   COLNAME    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
,   ROW_COUNT   BIGINT
)
@
BEGIN
    FOR C AS cur CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
        SELECT 'INSERT INTO FIND_VALUE SELECT '
            || '''' || TABSCHEMA || ''',''' || TABNAME || ''',''' || COLNAME || ''', COUNT(*) FROM '
            || '"' ||  TABSCHEMA || '"."' || TABNAME || '"'
            || ' WHERE "' || COLNAME || '" LIKE ''%' || x'1A' || '%''' AS S
        FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS C JOIN SYSCAT.TABLES T USING ( TABSCHEMA, TABNAME )
        WHERE C.CODEPAGE > 0 
        AND TABSCHEMA NOT IN ('SYSIBM','SYSTOOLS')
        AND T.TYPE IN ('T','S')
        ORDER BY
            TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, COLNAME
    DO       
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE C.S;
          COMMIT;
    END FOR;
END
```